# Change the image in the Inno Setup wizard banner

Tags: inno-setup

How do I change the image in the banner of wizards. I know how to change it in the first page, using this command:

```
WizardImageFile=C:\Documents and Settings\mybmp.bmp
```

But my question is about following pages, where it shows standard image banner at the top.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The banner at the top is controlled by the [`WizardSmallImageFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardsmallimagefile) directive. For example:

```
[Setup]
...
WizardSmallImageFile=mysmallimage.bmp
```

The maximum size of the bitmap is 55x58 pixels.

Comment: Thanks mirtheil, I just found out that. Much appreciated and thanks for the optimal size info.

Comment: If like me, you also wanted to change the large image on the left of the first installer page, you may follow the instructions on [this blog post](http://www.andrew-seaford.co.uk/custom-inno-theme/).

Comment: Also you need to make the image with 24 bits (R8 G8 B8), with Paint or Gimp is easy to do.